# How to get profile picture of user in Drupal from nodejs

Tags: node.js, file, drupal

In Drupal the profile image of user is stored as fid, and it can be retrieved in the Drupal php code base like this

```
file_create_url(file_load($user->picture)->uri)
```

where $user->picture is the fid and is retrievable from database directly in nodejs

But is it possible do the fid to file location conversion in nodejs so that the nodejs app can just read the fid from drupal database and find the file.

Thanks for help in advance,
Jib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not without re-implementing a lot of Drupal functionality. You can follow the trail of function calls back from [file_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_load/7) and [file_create_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) and you'll see what I mean.

Being that you probably can retrieve the filename from the FID in the database, one option is making an assumption on the path using the retrieved filename. For example, a MySQL query along the lines of `'SELECT filename FROM file_managed WHERE fid = ' + fid` and a URL assumption like `'/sites/default/files/image_style/' + filename`

Another likely less desirable option is creating a simple API endpoint or PHP script with Drupal bootstrap that returns the path. I say this is less desirable because you then have to make an HTTP request to Drupal and incur the overhead and latency associated with this request.

Comment: Thanks i can pull the url with info from file_managed table.Didn't notice that table earlier. Thanks a lot :)